# How can I use Springsource templates in Groovy on Grails Toolsuite?

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc

I am using Groovy on Grails Toolsuite 3.1.0.

I want to use a template for a Spring MVC application.

I am not finding the template where I would expect it in `File – > New -> New Spring Template Project -> Spring MVC Project`

Has anybody used SpringSource templates in Groovy on Grails Toolsuite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `help -> install new software` then I entered `http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e3.8` as the update site and installed Core, Extensions, Integrations, and Resources for Spring IDE.